# Can you create several "springSecurityFilterChain" with <http>?

Tags: spring-security

I'm configuring a web application to use spring-security. I'm using the xml namespace to configure the security with an "" element, as documented here : http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/2.0.x/reference/ns-config.html

As documented, the  namespace tag creates a single "springSecurityFilterChain" bean, that I can map to the URLs I need to secure using a "filter-mapping" in my web.xml

```
filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Now, I have two webapps that I somehow need to 'merge' into a common one ; each of those apps has a security configuration, and I would like to avoid having to create a third security configuration. What I would like to do is have *two* security filter chains configured by spring, with different bean nams, so that I can do :

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain1</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>


filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>


<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain1</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/foo/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/bar/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Would that make sense at all ?

The problem is, the  tag does not seem to provide a way to customize the name of the created bean. Is there one that I missed ? Or will I have to somehow duplicate what the  tag does with a FilterChain bean named as I want ?

Any ideas welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spring Security 3.1 you can do this, not with separate filters but with separate `<http>` elements in the namespace configuration.

From the [Spring Security 3.1 Reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-form-and-basic):

> From Spring Security 3.1 it is now possible to use multiple http
>   elements to define separate security filter chain configurations for
>   different request patterns.

Comment: does that mean we don't need `filter-mapping` right?